# Add class to before_widget for all widgets with a dropdown and a counter

Tags: theme-development, widgets, filters, css, sidebar

Some predefined widgets offer the option to use a `select` element (dropdown) and/or a counter after each entry. How can I add the CSS classes `widget-with-dropdown` or `widget-with-counters` to these widgets?

There are already solutions for [custom widgets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18942/add-class-to-before-widget-from-within-a-custom-widget/18945#18945), [known sidebar ids](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/widget-area-modify-paramxy-from-widget-n) or [positions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/535/how-do-i-add-custom-css-to-only-certain-widgets), but I have to inspect the parameters for the current instance, and I want to catch all possible positions or widgets (if they follow the WordPress naming scheme).

Comment: Why do you want to add classes? to style them or some other purpose?
Do you know what these widgets before hand (Your theme or plugin or a site you own) or a generic ones?

Comment: @SatishGandham Examples are the built-in widgets like the _Archive_ widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS classes are applied in the function `dynamic_sidebar()`. There is no specific filter for that:

```
// Substitute HTML id and class attributes into before_widget
$classname_ = '';
foreach ( (array) $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['classname'] as $cn ) {
    if ( is_string($cn) )
        $classname_ .= '_' . $cn;
    elseif ( is_object($cn) )
        $classname_ .= '_' . get_class($cn);
}
$classname_ = ltrim($classname_, '_');
$params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_);
```

But there is a filter for `$params` right after this code block:

```
$params = apply_filters( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', $params );
```

To get the settings for the current widget, we have to search in the global variable `$wp_registered_widgets` for an entry with the key `$params[ 0 ][ 'widget_id' ]`.
If it exists, it has a class instance as callback, and we can use that object’s method `get_settings()` to … well … get the settings.
The returned array has probably a key that equals `$params[1][ 'number' ]`.
Associated with this key is an array again, and here we might find another key `dropdown` (or `count`) with a value of `0` or `1`.
If it is `1`, we add the new classes to the string in `$params[0]['before_widget']`.

I think this easier to read as code:

```
is_admin() || add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse_widget_classes' );

/**
 * Add classes for widgets with counters or dropdowns.
 *
 * @param  array $params
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_widget_classes( $params ) {

    global $wp_registered_widgets;

    $classes     = array();
    $instance_id = $params[1][ 'number' ];
    $widget_id   = $params[ 0 ][ 'widget_id' ];
    $settings    = $wp_registered_widgets[ $widget_id ][ 'callback' ][ 0 ]->get_settings();

    if ( empty ( $settings[ $instance_id ] ) )
        return $params;

    if ( ! empty ( $settings[ $instance_id ][ 'dropdown' ] ) )
        $classes[] = 'widget-with-dropdown';

    if ( ! empty ( $settings[ $instance_id ][ 'count' ] ) )
        $classes[] = 'widget-with-counters';

    if ( empty ( $classes ) )
        return $params;

    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace(
        'class="',
        'class="' . join( ' ', $classes ) . ' ',
        $params[0]['before_widget']
    );

    return $params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just use a plugin:

- [Widget CSS Classes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/)
- [Custom Widget Classes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-widget-classes/)

Both plugins are doing pretty much the same as @toscho showed in his answer.

#### Widget CSS Classes plugin

```
$this_id    = $params[0]['id']; // Get the id for the current sidebar we're processing
$widget_id  = $params[0]['widget_id'];
$widget_obj = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id];
$widget_num = $widget_obj['params'][0]['number'];
```

<sup>[Source link to v1.2.1](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/widget-css-classes/tags/1.2.1/includes/widget-css-classes.class.php#L93)</sup>

#### Custom Widget Classes plugin

```
global $wp_registered_widgets;
$widget_id    = $params[0]['widget_id'];
$widget_obj    = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id];
$widget_opt    = get_option($widget_obj['callback'][0]->option_name);
$widget_num    = $widget_obj['params'][0]['number'];
```

<sup>[Source link to v1.1](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/custom-widget-classes/tags/1.1/custom-widget-classes.php#L247)</sup>

*Just to prove that @toscho is right and there seems to be no other option to go on this.*

Comment: Plugins might go away eventually, and we want to collect solutions, not links. :)

Comment: OK - sorry - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

first add a custom placeholder class in the constructor

```
<?php
public function __construct() {
   $widget_ops  = array(
      'classname'                   =>; 'widget_text eaa __eaa__', //__eaa__ is my placeholder css class
      'description'                 =>; __( 'AdSense ads, arbitrary text, HTML or JS.','eaa' ),
      'customize_selective_refresh' =>; true,
   );
   $control_ops = array( 'width' =>; 400, 'height' =>; 350 );
   parent::__construct( 'eaa', __( 'Easy AdSense Ads &amp; Scripts', 'eaa' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
}
?>
```

Then replace it with the class/es of your choice based on the widget options like this

```
<?php
if ( $instance['no_padding'] ) {
   $args['before_widget'] = str_replace( '__eaa__', 'eaa-clean', $args['before_widget'] );
}
?>
```

We are using the place holder to limit the ways in which the html of before_widget may affect our plugin functionality

You can find the details with example at
http://satishgandham.com/2017/03/adding-dynamic-classes-custom-wordpress-widgets/

Comment: I want to catch all widgets with these properties, not only my own. For those, I can just do anything I want. :)