# How add short description Featured Products or Related Products

Tags: widgets, plugins, description

I would like to have a short description in the widget *Featured Products* or before the list *Related Products*.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Featured Products* is a widget. Inserting content here is tricky, because there is no real hook. But what the widget does is a simple call to `WP_Query`, and here we can use the action `loop_start`. We just have to make sure to find the correct `loop_start`, because there are probably many more on each page.

So first create a function for the description:

```
function print_woo_featured_products_desc()
{
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    echo 'This is my description.';
}
```

This function removes itself from the current filter (`loop_start`) and prints your description. Now we have to activate it somewhere:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', function() {

    add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', function( $params )
    {
        if ( $params[0]['widget_name'] === __( 'WooCommerce Featured Products', 'woocommerce' ) )
            add_action( 'loop_start', 'print_woo_featured_products_desc' );

        return $params;
    });
});
```

Explaining what happens would take too much time. And I did that already:

- [Add class to before_widget for all widgets with a dropdown and a counter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108400/add-class-to-before-widget-for-all-widgets-with-a-dropdown-and-a-counter)
- [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars)

The related products are a template. Just copy `woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php` to your theme into `/themename/woocommerce/single-product/related.php`, and add your description after

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```